Finding the smallest value of $\sqrt{x^2+(1 - y)^2} + \sqrt{y^2+(1 - x)^2}$

Find the smallest value of the expression:
$$\sqrt{x^2+(1 - y)^2} + \sqrt{y^2+(1 - x)^2}$$

I've inserted it in the desmos 3d and I see the answer is $\sqrt{2}$, but how do I prove it?

Note that the expression is $|(x,y)-(0,1)|+ |(x,y)-(1,0)|$ which would suggest looking at the triangle inequality

But what have you tried? Everybody can do it by Desmos or WolframAlpha. Etc.

If we restrict $(x, y)\in [0,1]^2$, then it becomes obvious that the point $(x, y)$ together with the paralleles to the coordinate axes through it would dissect the unit square into 4 rectangular regions. Moreover it is clear that then your expression is just the diagonal of the upper left rectangle plus the diagonal of the lower right triangle, when applying to those the formula of Pythagoras.

Furthermore you ask for the minimum of that sum of lengths. It ought be pretty clear that this can only be achieved, if those diagonals are mutually parallel. But this again restricts the choice of the point to be on the second diagonal of the square, i.e. $y=1-x$.
But then again you could interchange the upper and lower rectangles each to see that the asked for 2 diagonals happen to outline the main diagonal of the square, the length of which clearly is $\sqrt 2$. - Alternatively you could insert the above result into your formula to obtain
$$\sqrt{x^2+(1-(1-x))^2}+\sqrt{(1-x)^2+(1-x)^2}=x\sqrt{1+1}+(1-x)\sqrt{1+1}=1\sqrt 2$$
--- rk

I think you should have drawn the yellowish diagonals the other way.

that does neither change their lengths nor is needed because addition is commutative

We have three nice geometric answers, one in the comments, already.
The standard solution in calculus and simplest here is to define the function $f(x,y)=A+B$ where $A=\sqrt{x^2+(y-1)^2}$ and $B=\sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2},$ and then to find critical points of this function.
The critical points occur when $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=0$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=0$ or when one of partial derivatives is undefined. The latter case is usually not important.
So, we need to solve the system
$$\frac xA=\frac{x-1}B\tag1$$
$$\frac{y-1}A=\frac yB\tag2$$
Now, dividing $(1)$ by $(2)$, we get
$$x+y=1.\tag3$$
Can you take it from here?
